# PHP Remove Extension with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically im making a IDE Website:
http://dev7ide.grn.cc

And anyway, I am wanting the URL to rewrite from project.php?id=someid to project?id=someid

I can remember some of it but dont know it of by heart.

Comment: You could just answer my simple question to get better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only php extension you could do this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1
```

If you want to remove any extension you could do this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.[^\.]+$ $1
```